# SQL*Loader problem

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sql-loader

I am getting an error [SQL*Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#What_is_SQL.2ALoader_and_what_is_it_used_for.3F)-606, which means:

> The synonym specified in the INTO
>   TABLE clause in the SQL*Loader control
>   file specifies a remote object via a
>   database link. Only a synonym for an
>   existing local table can be specified
>   in the INTO TABLE clause.

Is there any way we can insert into remote table using SQL*Loader?

Comment: Which version of the database are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are on 10g you can use External Tables instead of SQL Loader.

Setting up an External Table is easy.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011).

To get the External Table to pick up a new file (which you may need to do because you have a repeating process), do this:

```
alter table your_ext_table_name location ('<newfile.name>')
/
```

Then you can do this:

```
insert into whatever_table@remote_db
    select * from your_ext_table_name 
/
```

This avoids two lots of DML.  External tables are not as fast as a well-tuned SQL*Loader process, but that will be trivial compared to the network traffic tax (which is unavoidable in your scenario).

Answer (score 2):

```
create table temp_table as select * from remote_table@remote_db where 1 = 2;

load using sql*loader into temp_table;

insert into remote_table@remote_db select * from temp_table;
```

Comment: +1 Most SQL*Loader problems are easier to solve in SQL.  That's why External Tables are such a boon.

Comment: @Robert .Thanks for the suggestion but if the table is a huge table! then dont you think that this will take a hell lot of time to insert and also to create and this should be perfomed regularly in the form of a process,so this i am afraid will be a feasible solution or not!!

Comment: Then why don't you let sqlldr connect to the remote database
sqlldr username/password@tnsalias
You have acces to the remote database using the tnsalias otherwise the databaselink would not work

Comment: Yes ,Robert I am doing the same but the problem is as i mentioned above INTO TABLE clause will take a synonym which is for a local existing table:)

Comment: @crasher: Robert is saying don't connect to your local database and hit the other database over a database link... hit the other database directly.  SQL*Loader can connect to remote databases directly, it just can't insert into a database link.  Connect directly to remote_db.  Don't use your local database as an intermediary.

Answer (score 1):

Run SQL Loader on the server that has the table?

Must be a reason why not, but this seems the simplest to me.

Comment: I dont have an access to that server to run nythg on it.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't use external tables (eg because the data file is on a client machine rather than on the database server), you can insert into a view on the remote object.

For example

```
create database link schema1 connect to schema1 identified by schema1 using 'XE';
create view schema1_test_vw as select * from test@schema1;

load data
 infile *
 append
 into table schema1_test_vw
 ( id POSITION(1:4) INTEGER)
begindata
1001
1002
1003
```

succeeded on my XE test.
For a view all the column sizes,datatypes etc are fixed on the local schema so sqlldr doesn't have a problem.